# Issue with Solidity's call Function Redirecting to Fallback Instead of Target Function

Tags: solidity

#### Description

I'm encountering an issue in Solidity where using the 'call' function to invoke a specific function in a contract redirects to the fallback function instead. The target function (bar) is not marked as payable, and direct calls to it work correctly. See below:

#### Body

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >= 0.8.0;

contract ReceiveContract {
    
    event ReceiveLog(address caller, uint amount, string message);
    receive() external payable { 
        emit ReceiveLog(msg.sender, msg.value, "Receive.");
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        emit ReceiveLog(msg.sender, msg.value, "Fallback.");
    }

     function bar(string memory _s, uint _n) external returns (uint) {
        emit ReceiveLog(msg.sender, 0, _s);
        return _n+1;
    }
}

contract CallContract {
    ReceiveContract receiver;
    constructor() {
        receiver = new ReceiveContract();
    }
    event DoLog(address caller, bool ok, bytes b);
    function do4() external {
        (bool ok, bytes memory b) = address(receiver).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("bar(string,uint)", "hello", 3)); // not work, receiver redirect to fallback()
        // receiver.bar("hello", 7);   // this line work
        emit DoLog(msg.sender, ok, b);
    }
}
```

All code I write in Remix.
I tried:
`(bool ok, bytes memory b) = address(receiver).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("bar(string,uint)", "hello", 3));` but not work.

And tried:
`receiver.bar("hello", 7);` this work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uint` is an alias for `uint256`. The function signature needs to include the full type name, including its length.

```
// `uint256` instead of `uint`
abi.encodeWithSignature("bar(string,uint256)", "hello", 3)
```

---

From the [docs page](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.24/abi-spec.html#types):

> *`uint`, `int`: synonyms for `uint256`, `int256` respectively. For computing the function selector, `uint256` and `int256` have to be used.*